# On what basis are choices of trigonometric functions made when dealing with waves or oscillations in physics?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, conventions, oscillators

Up until this morning, I thought the choice between sine and cosine was arbitrary as both of them have a similar $x-y$ curve when graphed with the difference being that cosine is $\frac{π}{2}$ ahead of sine.

For example, my books make use of the sine function when dealing with AC voltage:

$$v = v_msin({\omega}t)$$

When dealing with displacement produced by a needle in rippling water, I notice I have displacement $y$:

$$y = acos({\omega}t)$$

When I thought about it, I noticed that the $\frac{π}{2}$ difference probably means a lot.

At time $t = 0$, for AC current, I would have $0$ voltage; for water rippling, I would have maximum displacement.

Would I be right in saying that the choice between functions is *not* arbitrary? And if not, please elaborate.

Comment: It's just choosing a different time origin.

Comment: So if I adopted a cosine instead of a sine for dealing with a time-varying quantity, say, for an electromagnetic wave, my results wouldn't be wrong as long as I stuck to my function of choice for both the electric and magnetic component? Thanks!

Comment: There's absolutely no difference, both work. As you said, if you know that a quantity has to be zero at position/time zero (say you're writing a standing wave, and a hard wall boundary condition is at $x = 0$), then sine is a bit more convenient, but it's certainly not wrong to use cosine with a phase shift.

Comment: The choice is often due to boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on the initial conditions.  In fact the general solution is 
$$
x(t)=a\cos(\omega t)+ b\sin(\omega t)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are often determined at $t=0$ from $x(0)=a$ and 
$\dot x(0)=\omega b$.

Comment: I find this to be a weirdly intuitive way of looking at it! Thanks!

Comment: In what way is this weird?  The differential equation for harmonic motion is $\ddot x=-\omega^2 x$.  Since this is second order the general solution must contain two arbitrary constants determined from the initial conditions.